# SwiftUI list view unexpected behaviour - Shrinks on appearing

Tags: ios, swift, listview, swiftui

I'm building an iOS app using SwiftUI and some list views shrink a little horizontally, not so much but also not so small to ignore, on appearing in the screen.

The behavior is not consistent for all list views and I am unable to find any reasons.

I guessed that this might occur when rows have Navigation links, but the issue happened on lists without navigation links also.

I've added the screen recording two list views from the iDine app (refer - HackingWithSwift Paul Hudson's tutorial).

Note that the favorites list shrinks and the menu list doesn't shrink.

[image: shaking list view from iDine app]

Here's the code for favorites.

```
List {
   ForEach(favorites.items) { item in
      MainMenuRow(item: item)
   }
```

}

And Here's the code for the menu.

```
List {
   ForEach(menu.sections) { section in
       Section(header: Text(section.name)) {
          ForEach(section.items) { item in
               MainMenuRow(item: item)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using TableViewController to fix this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60379018/4577610